# Dynamic memory allocation - default-initialization of primitive types in c++

Tags: c++, initialization, memory-management

If I allocate an array of some primitive type e.g.

```
double *v = new double[10];
```

I need to know, what the inital value of the array entries will be.

Is it specified in the standard or compiler dependend and where can I find it.

Thanks,
Johannes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, the array contents are not initialized. You need to use `double *v = new double[10]();` to have the default value of `0` for each element (Notice `()`).

Comment: Which is totally non obvious and very likely to pass unnoticed in code reviews... :/

Comment: @Matthieu: Very true. Even Naveen suspected this, so he wrote `Notice ()`. haha

Comment: OTOH, having human eyes check for errors better detected by a tool is not what code reviews should be about.

Comment: @Nawaz ,is there a reference about the `()`?

Comment: @compile-fan: Regarding the syntax `T()`, §8.5/7 says `An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.` and §8.5/5 says `— if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;`.  And value-initialization of element of type `double` means zero-initialization.